# Populate excel sheet with C#

Tags: c#, excel, data-structures

I am going wrong with the structure of my program. My Excel sheet should update a cell with data every time when I press a button in my windows form application.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace Test6attendance
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

        if (File.Exists("D:\\login.xlscsharp-Excel.xls"))
        {

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\\login.xlscsharp-Excel.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            for (int i = 1; i < 55555; i++)
            {


                if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] == null)
                {

                    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/ yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");
                    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\login.xlscsharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                    xlApp.Quit();

                    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                    releaseObject(xlApp);

                    MessageBox.Show("Excel file updated , you can find the file D:\\csharp-Excel.xls");

                }

            }



        }
        else
        {

            //Create New Code



            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);




            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/ yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");


            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\login.xlscsharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file D:\\csharp-Excel.xls");

        }
    }
         private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }


}
```

I believe the problem is with the for loop, it does not seem to work. Need some suggestion or reference to fix it.

Comment: You should save `xlWorkBook.Worksheets` as a separate variable otherwise you are not fully cleaning up all used objects.

Comment: Also, it is worth putting your code in a `try/catch` and clean up in the `finally` so you don't risk any object leaks.

Comment: How to do that? I am trying it but there is no option to save xlWorkBook.Worksheets, only SaveAs is available and I am getting error with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with

```
if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] == null)
```

It should be

```
 if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] == null)
```

Since your first if condition checks if file exist `if (File.Exists("D:\\login.xlscsharp-Excel.xls"))`, if not then it creates a file and assigns the value to cell[1,1]. Now when you click the second time the cell is not null and your value doesn't gets updated.

try this code

```
for (int i = 1; i < 55555; i++)
            {


                if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] != null)
                {

                    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/ yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");
                    xlWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\login.xlscsharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                    xlApp.Quit();

                    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                    releaseObject(xlApp);

                    MessageBox.Show("Excel file updated , you can find the file D:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
                    break;

                }

            }
```

Comment: Now I am getting a message to replace the existing file and gives me a   message "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Test6attendance.exe

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Comment: The code must to replace the data in existing cell, if the previous cell has some value, it should check the next cell whether it is blank and only if it is blank it should write value into it. If the file is existing, it should update it without changing previous entries. The new value should be entered to the next cell which is blank.

Comment: If I am using      
      
    if(xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] != null) 
instead of 
    
    if(xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] != null)

How can I complete my task?

Comment: ok if you want to enter value in next cell which is blank then you should use `if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] == null)` updating my ans, try it again

Comment: I am going wrong somewhere, I tried both the way. Still I am unable to populate the next row. It is not updating to next cell, since I have given it in for loop and I have all other cells blank, I believe I should get value in all other cells but even that is not happening.

Comment: try this `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].ToString()){
//code here
}`

Comment: Now it is asking to replace my existing file rather than updating it. When I clicked replace it gave an error. This happened with my previous code also.

I tried this code as you have suggested:
        for (int i = 1; i < 55555; i++)
        {
        if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] != null)
                    {

                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] =    DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/ yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");
                break;
                 }
                } 
Still getting same error

Comment: I finally found that "xlWorkBook.SaveAs" statement is causing the error. I am unable to edit and update the existing file, instead it is asking me to replace my old file. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Try Save() instead of SaveAs(). SaveAs expects a different filename. Also check my answer below.

Comment: I am not able to do it, still getting error. There is no save option only saveas is available.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is quite strange. You should put all of the code in the loop outside of the loop. The only thing that you should leave in it is the line where you assign the value. Otherwise you save the app for each line you save. Not to mention that you release all your objects after you assign the first value. I would guess this could only write one value and then raise many exceptions in the first line of your for loop (you try to get worksheet from a workbook object that you already released).

It should be something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 55555; i++)
{
   if (xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] != null)
   {
       xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/ yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt"); 
   }
}
xlWorkBook.Save("D:\\login.xlscsharp-Excel.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
MessageBox.Show("Excel file updated , you can find the file D:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
```